# Computed Column Get Value From Another Tables Column Based On Current Tables Value

Tags: sql-server

Today's question is more of a, is it possible, which I am sure it is, I probably just don't know the correct syntax, due to my lack of knowledge and experience. I have scoured the web, but as usual couldn't find a relevant example that applies to answer my question.

So I have four tables.

One called Type.
One called SubType.
One called Model.

And finally Asset. The Asset is supposed to store the ID of each of the above. However I am looking at automating how Type and SubType are calculated. Storing Type and SubType values against specific Models.

So if I reference the ID of Model in Asset.
Is there any way of using a computed column to get the value of Type and SubType from the Model table and auto calculate it in Asset.
I am looking at removing the user's need to manually manage these values.

Here is my code so far, as you will see in the Asset Table, I am only using foreign keys and IDs at the moment. Any advice and assistance is appreciated!

```
CREATE TABLE AssetType
(
AssetTypeID TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT AssetTypeID PRIMARY KEY (AssetTypeID),
AssetTypeTitle VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT AssetTypeTitleUniqueConstraint UNIQUE
)

CREATE TABLE AssetSubType
(
AssetSubTypeID TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT AssetSubTypeID PRIMARY KEY (AssetSubTypeID),
AssetSubTypeTitle VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT AssetSubTypeTitleUniqueConstraint UNIQUE,
AssetSubTypeAssetTypeID TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT AssetSubTypeAssetTypeID FOREIGN KEY (AssetSubTypeAssetTypeID) REFERENCES AssetType(AssetTypeID)
)

CREATE TABLE Model
(
ModelID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONSTRAINT ModelIDDefault DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ModelID PRIMARY KEY (ModelID),
ModelTitle VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
ModelManufacturerID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ModelManufacturerID FOREIGN KEY (ModelManufacturerID) REFERENCES Manufacturer(ManufacturerID),
ModelOrganisationID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ModelOrganisationID FOREIGN KEY (ModelOrganisationID) REFERENCES Organisation(OrganisationID),
CONSTRAINT ManufacturerUnique UNIQUE (ModelTitle, ModelManufacturerID, ModelOrganisationID),
ModelAssetTypeID TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ModelAssetTypeID FOREIGN KEY (ModelAssetTypeID) REFERENCES AssetType(AssetTypeID),
ModelAssetSubTypeID TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ModelAssetSubTypeID FOREIGN KEY (ModelAssetSubTypeID) REFERENCES AssetSubType(AssetSubTypeID),
ModelCITypeID TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ModelCITypeID FOREIGN KEY (ModelCITypeID) REFERENCES CIType(CITypeID),
ModelCISubTypeID TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT ModelCISubTypeID FOREIGN KEY (ModelCISubTypeID) REFERENCES CISubType(CISubTypeID)
)

CREATE TABLE HardwareAsset
(
HardwareAssetID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER CONSTRAINT HardwareAssetIDDefault DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT HardwareAssetID PRIMARY KEY (HardwareAssetID),
HardwareAssetTitle VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
HardwareAssetAssetStatusID TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT HardwareAssetAssetStatusID FOREIGN KEY (HardwareAssetAssetStatusID) REFERENCES AssetStatus(AssetStatusID),
HardwareAssetAssetTypeID TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT HardwareAssetAssetTypeID FOREIGN KEY (HardwareAssetAssetTypeID) REFERENCES AssetType(AssetTypeID),
HardwareAssetAssetSubTypeID TINYINT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT HardwareAssetAssetSubTypeID FOREIGN KEY (HardwareAssetAssetSubTypeID) REFERENCES AssetSubType(AssetSubTypeID),
HardwareAssetAssetTag VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT HardwareAssetAssetTagUnique UNIQUE,
HardwareAssetSerialNumber VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT HardwareAssetSerialNumber UNIQUE,
HardwareAssetManufacturerID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT HardwareAssetManufacturerID FOREIGN KEY (HardwareAssetManufacturerID) REFERENCES Manufacturer(ManufacturerID),
HardwareAssetModelID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT HardwareAssetModelID FOREIGN KEY (HardwareAssetModelID) REFERENCES Model(ModelID),
)
```

Comment: code is incomplete, I think, e.g.,where is `Model.ModelAssetTypeID` ?

Comment: Is your `HardwareAsset.HardwareAssetAssetTypeId` going to be different from the `Model.ModelAssetTypeId` ?

Comment: that is in there:

    ModelAssetTypeID TINYINT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ModelAssetTypeID FOREIGN KEY (ModelAssetTypeID) REFERENCES AssetType(AssetTypeID),

Comment: Yes I want the ModelAssetTypeID to be pushed into the HardwareAssetAssetTypeID

Comment: Why do you want this value stored in two places? it will be accessible from the Model table. For that matter, so is the subtype. Duplicating these data values in the child table violates normalization, allows for bad code to create inconsistent values, and creates the non-problem you are trying to solve. Just have any client code look it up by performing a join to the parent table.

Comment: @JoelKilduff I have to say, for someone who lacks "knowledge and experience" you are putting a lot of thought and effort into your design, good job so far! You might want to check out [Louis Davidson's presentations of database design on his website](http://www.drsql.org/presentations-1)

Comment: @SqlZim thanks, I am certainly a novice and don't know best practices, but would rather spend the time designing right the first time, than coming back later and trying to clean it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want this value stored in two places? it will be accessible from the Model table. For that matter, so is the subtype. Duplicating these data values in the child table violates normalization, allows for bad code to create inconsistent values, and creates the non-problem you are trying to solve. Just have any client code look it up by performing a join to the parent table.

If you seriously want a database artifact to include the data from multiple tables, create a `view` (using joins), that has all the table columns you want, in a flattened structure, and have you client SQL code use that view instead.

Comment: to be honest i didnt even consider that it would be more simple to get this via a JOIN and as a matter of completeness for the table just thought this was a good place to store, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The best course of action, in my opinion, would be to simply query the `Model.TypeId` and `Model.SubTypeId` using an `inner join` between `HardwareAsset` and `Model` whenever you need those values.

If you insist on having the `Model.TypeId` and `Model.SubTypeId` in the `HardwareAsset` table with a computed column:

- You need to do it with a scalar function call that gets the `Model.TypeId` and a separate scalar function that gets the `Model.SubTypeId` for a given `ModelId`.
- These computed column are referencing another table, so they will be be `non-deterministic`.
  You can **not** index `non-deterministic` computed columns. 
  This means you will be invoking two scalar functions per row in the `HardwareAsset` every time you are trying to check those values. That will get very slow pretty quickly.

One alternative if you insist on storing the `Model.TypeId` and `Model.SubTypeId` in the `HardwareAsset` table would be to pull in the `Model.TypeId` and `Model.SubTypeId` every time a row in the `HardwareAsset` table is inserted or updated. Regardless of how you implement it, it still breaks one of the rules of database normalization.

One last alternative, use a view:

```
go
create view dbo.HardwareAsset_with_ModelInfo as 
select 
    HardwareAssetId
  , HardwareAssetTitle
  , HardwareAssetAssetStatusId
  , HardwareAssetAssetTypeId    = m.ModelAssetTypeID 
  , HardwareAssetAssetSubTypeId = m.ModelAssetSubTypeID
  , HardwareAssetAssetTag
  , HardwareAssetSerialNumber
  , HardwareAssetManufacturerId = m.ModelManufacturerId
  , HardwareAssetModelId
from HardwareAsset as ha
  inner join Model as m
    on ha.HardwareAssetModelId = m.ModelId
go
```

Comment: to be honest i didnt even consider that it would be more simple to get this via a JOIN and as a matter of completeness for the table just thought this was a good place to store, thanks for your help